# Using gethostbyaddr with app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to user gethostbyaddr in Google App Engine - Python.

I have

```
import socket
```

and then

```
class BeatMail(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        refer = self.request.remote_addr
        referName = socket.gethostbyaddr(refer)
        self.response.out.write(referName)
```

But I'm getting erros on socket.gethostbyaddr(refer) line. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`socket` is disabled in the AppEngine API. See [runtime docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#The_Sandbox).

Answer (score 0):

`gethostbyaddr` is unluckily not supported yet, there's an open feature request [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=354).